# REST API query not returning on when multiple results

Tags: powershell, rest, servicenow

I have a simple query running on ServiceNow API

```
...
$headers = @{“authorization” = “Bearer $token”}
$Type = "application/json"
$getincidents = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri "$($body.env)/api/now/v2/table/the_table?sysparm_query=number=55AAD55" -Headers $headers -ContentType $Type
$getincidents.result | Export-Csv -Path .\Processes.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This returns my single query result fine. When I try to replace `/api/now/v2/table/the_table?sysparm_query=number=55AAD55` with something more generic that has multiple results

```
/api/now/v2/table/the_table?sysparm_query=opened_by_department=IT Finance
```

My query fails and doesn't return anything. What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: What is the error when "it fails" - specifically is it on the server side or powershell? Try manually replacing the spaces in your uri with `%20`?

Comment: It just doesn't return anything

Comment: make sure that `$getincidents` is actually blank. Try removing the `-ContentType` parameter. Try replacing `Invoke-RestMethod` with `Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Method GET -Uri $uri` since it's a little more forgiving about responses. Make extra sure your query actually returns results on `the_table`.